# C# XOR operators: ^ vs ^= and implicit type conversion

Tags: c#

I've noticed something odd about using the bitwise XOR operator on `byte`s in C#.  Odd to my mind, at least.

```
byte a = 0x11;
byte b = 0xAA;
a ^= b;         // works
a = a ^ b;      // compiler error: Cannot implicitly convert type "int" to "byte"
```

I also see this issue using `short`, but not `int` or `long`.

I thought the last two lines were equivalent, but that doesn't seem to be the case. What's going on here?

Comment: I agree it looks strange. @matthew-flaschen nailed it, though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no xor operator that takes and returns bytes.  So C# implicitly widens the input bytes to ints.  However, it does *not* implicitly narrow the result int.  Thus, you get the given error on the second line.  However, §14.14.2 (compound assignment) of [the standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf) provides that:

> if the return
>   type of the selected operator is
>   explicitly convertible to the type of
>   x, and if y is implicitly convertible
>   to the type of x or the operator is a
>   shift operator, then the operation is
>   evaluated as x = (T)(x op y), where T
>   is the type of x, except that x is
>   evaluated only once.

x and y (the inputs) are both bytes.  You can explicitly narrow a int to a byte, and clearly a byte is implicitly convertible to a byte.  Thus, there is an implicit cast.

Answer (score 1):

In most C-like languages, operators will promote types smaller than `int` to `int`.

In such languages, `a op= b` is equivalent to `a = (typeof a)(a op b)`